# str to pkcs7 struct with rust crypto

Tags: rust, pkcs#7, rust-crypto

I'm trying to convert a Python lib to a Rust one. In this process I need to extract x509 certs from a pkcs7 (or at least the oids).

In Python I used the lib Cryptography:

```py
from typing import List
import base64

from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import pkcs7

my_sig: str = "something"
signature_decoded: bytes = base64.b64decode(my_sig)
pkcs_certs: List[x509.Certificate] = pkcs7.load_der_pkcs7_certificates(signature_decoded)
```

Here `my_sig` is a detached PKCS #7 signature, Base64 encoded as string.

To do my Rust equivalent I tried to use [rust crypto](https://github.com/RustCrypto). But from what I saw the [pkcs7 format](https://docs.rs/pkcs7/latest/pkcs7/) is only a struct and don't implement the loading part.

That said I assume I need to implement a trait from the lib that loads my u8 pkcs7 as a pkcs7 struct but I can't find any [simple example](https://docs.rs/der/latest/der/#example).

What I have for now:

asn1_extractor.rs

```rust
use der::{
    asn1::{Any, ObjectIdentifier},
    Decodable, Decoder, Encodable, Sequence
};

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct AlgorithmIdentifier<'a> {
    pub algorithm: ObjectIdentifier,

    pub parameters: Option<Any<'a>>
}

impl<'a> Decodable<'a> for AlgorithmIdentifier<'a> {
    fn decode(decoder: &mut Decoder<'a>) -> der::Result<Self> {
        decoder.sequence(|decoder| {
            let algorithm = decoder.decode()?;
            let parameters = decoder.decode()?;
            Ok(Self { algorithm, parameters })
        })
    }
}

impl<'a> Sequence<'a> for AlgorithmIdentifier<'a> {
    fn fields<F, T>(&self, field_encoder: F) -> der::Result<T>
        where
            F: FnOnce(&[&dyn Encodable]) -> der::Result<T>,
    {
        field_encoder(&[&self.algorithm, &self.parameters])
    }
}
```

lib.rs

```rust
extern crate core;

use pkcs7;
use der::{Decodable, ValueOrd, Decoder, Sequence};

pub mod asn1_extractor;


pub fn pkcs7_oid_verifier(signature: String) -> () {
    let bytes = base64::decode(signature).unwrap();
    let mut decoder = Decoder::new(&bytes).expect("bruh it doesn work :(");
    let asn1 = asn1_extractor::AlgorithmIdentifier::decode(&mut decoder);
    // ===> here I want to have a pkcs7 struct as result of the fn
}
```